# I'm using the mssql database and I have an API so I can get the data from it. But I can't access database using react native

Tags: sql-server, react-native, api, postman

I'm using the mssql database and I have an API so I can get the data from it. But I can't access database using react native. The data I can pull is only the field defined in the body part in Postman. How can I access all the data in the database. Thanks.`

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

const obj = JSON.parse(raw);
const obj2=JSON.parse(obj.LisansTerminal);

```
var raw = JSON.stringify({
  "KullaniciKodu": "001",
  "KullaniciSifresi": "001",
  "LisansTerminal": "{\"Id\":1060,\"SubeId\":5,\"Durum\":0,\"Adi\":\"NEXUS\",\"SeriNumarasi\":\"L2NDU19823001982\",\"EvrenselNumara\":\"fbc72efc7920b71f\",\"Marka\":\"\",\"Model\":\"\",\"Uretici\":\"\",\"OlusturmaTarihi\":\"2019-10-20T20:45:28.22\"}"
});

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: raw,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("http://localhost/Login.svc/example", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

```
 const myFunc = () => {
    if (isLoading) {
      return <ActivityIndicator size="small" color={"red"}/>;
    }
    if (userName===obj.KullaniciKodu && number === obj.KullaniciSifresi) {
   return navigation.navigate("UserLogin", {firma:"CODES-EBRU",kullanici:obj.KullaniciKodu,donem:"2022", sube:"MERKEZ", kasa:'ANA KASA' })}
   else {
      return Alert.alert("Hatalı Giriş", "Tekrar Deneyiniz")
   }
  };
```

`

Access database datas and using them login page.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to access to DB using already prepared API. I used fetch("http://localhost/Login.svc/example", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));  but I saw only "raw",'s datas.